# How to detect the other side has called shutdown() on a TCP socket?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

Say, a tcp client has connected to a tcp server on socket s. Next, the client call `shutdown(s);` then how should the server detect that the client has did that operation?

PS: I have known the server will receive FD_CLOSE. However, I don't know how to check that flag on the server side.

Comment: Take a look at the discussion here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091010/recv-socket-function-returning-data-with-length-as-0

Answer (score 4):

From winsock's [recv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description:

> If the connection has been gracefully closed, the return value is zero.

Getting zero byte count from `recv`,`WSARecv` (or `ReadFile`) is the common way to learn that the other side has closed the connection.

Comment: Thanks. But a related question follows: How to call recv in non-block way to check that? Does ioctlsocket help?

Comment: @xmllmx: Use `select()` with a timeout.

Comment: How would you get data if it *weren't* closed? (You could use overlapped I/O, or non-blocking mode, or `WSAEventSelect`, or `WSAAsyncSelect`, whatever you want. But you surely read the data *somewhere* -- just check for zero byte count in *that* place)

Answer (score 1):

xmllmx - Don't call recv() to check if the socket has closed, use select() and ask it to signal when the socket is readable or writable.  Note also that unless you're just writing a demo for class you most likely want to set your sockets to non-blocking mode anyway as calling recv() with too big of a buffer will cause it to block, so will causing send() with a buffer that can't fit into the OS's buffer, etc...

Finally, using select() is pretty terrible in Winsock as well; you probably want to use one of the forms of Overlapped I/O, such as completion routines or completion ports.