# Single socket connection with multiple logical data streams (differentiating packets)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I’m making a program in C++ using windows sockets where I want a single socket but the ability to send data from different threads and distinguish server side which thread sent the data as they have different applications. Essentially logical data streams using a single socket connection. I’m having trouble finding a way to differentiate the packets server side. The best I can think of is starting each packet with a few bytes indicating which thread has sent it. Are there any better ways to be doing this?

Similar to [How to use single port for multiple logical data streams (Winsock)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331003/how-to-use-single-port-for-multiple-logical-data-streams-winsock) but I'm stuck at differentiating the packets.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet (I think) is to associate a unique id with each task, create a single thread that handles the networking and (as you said) adds the task-id to the packet.

On the receiver side you do the same: a single thread reads the packets and distributes their content according to the task-id.

Answer (score 0):

If the so-called packets are not all of a fixed length that the server knows, you need also an indication where a packet starts or ends.