# Communication between Cpp and PHP

Tags: php, c++

hey so I've been looking around a lot but i couldn't get a accurate answer and I want to communicate php and c++ with sockets and i have spend hours trying to find any example but I cannot find.

server:

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
    SOCKADDR_IN server_addr, client_addr;

    int wsa = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);
    if (wsa != 0)
        return;

    const auto server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1111);

    ::bind(server, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr));
    listen(server, 0);
    printf("listening for connections\n");

    int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    for (;;)
    {
        SOCKET client;
        if ((client = accept(server, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&client_addr), &client_addr_size)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            SOCKET soc = client;
            string str = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);

            std::cout << "connec" << std::endl;
            char dobj[1024];
           auto n = recv(soc, dobj, 1024, 0);

           std::cout << n << std::endl;
           std::cout << dobj << std::endl;
        }

        const auto last_error = WSAGetLastError();

        if (last_error > 0)
        {
            printf("error: %i\n", last_error);
        }
    }
    closesocket(server);
    WSACleanup();
```

client:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $query = $_GET['query'];
        echo $query;
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $service_port = 1111;
        $address = "localhost";

        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if ($socket === false){
            echo "Failed: ". socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\n";
        }

        echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...'\n";
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);

        if ($result === false){
            echo "Failed: ". socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\n";
        }

        $in = $query;
        $out = '';

        echo "Sending...\n";  
        socket_send($socket, $in, strlen($in), MSG_WAITALL);
        echo "OK.\n";

        echo "Reading response:\n\n";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 10)) {
            echo $out;
        }

        socket_close($socket);
    }
?>
```

here are my few attemts my code says success for connect and the php side is just stuck on sending and i cant figure it out

Comment: did you have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362376/socket-connection-between-php-and-c) ?

Comment: yes but it is just stuck on it

Comment: so, what exactly have you tried? can you provide the relevant part of your c++/php code?

Comment: i edited the post can you please check

Answer (score 1):

I made some tiny changes in your code and got it working. Depending on what exactly you want to do you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

*In short:* I changed PHP `socket_send` to `socket_write` (because `socket_send` seems to wait "forever") and changed `while ($out = socket_read($socket, 10))` to `while ($out = socket_read($socket, 10) > 0)` because the loop won't stop after the first receive.
In C++ I added `send(soc, "got msg!", 10, 0);` after `recv()` to send a message back to PHP (which PHP waits for).

In the code below the C++ program should be started first. It waits for an established connection, prints some text it receives and "answeres" with `"got msg!"`.
The PHP script then connects to the socket, sends some string, waits for a response
and prints it. Be aware that PHP cannot run forever, only just for a few seconds, depending on your server. So you should consider a design, where PHP just gets called to send and receive **one** message!

C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    SOCKADDR_IN server_addr, client_addr;

    int wsa = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);
    if (wsa != 0)
        return 1;

    const auto server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1111);

    bind(server, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr));
    listen(server, 0);
    printf("listening for connections\n");

    int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
    for (;;)
    {
        SOCKET client;
        if ((client = accept(server, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&client_addr), &client_addr_size)) != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            SOCKET soc = client;
            std::string str = inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr);

            std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
            char dobj[1024];
            auto n = recv(soc, dobj, 1024, 0);

            std::cout << n << std::endl;
            std::cout << dobj << std::endl;

            // I added the following two lines:
            send(soc, "got msg!", 10, 0);
            std::cout << "sent response" << std::endl;
        }

        const auto last_error = WSAGetLastError();

        if (last_error > 0)
        {
            printf("error: %i\n", last_error);
        }
    }
    closesocket(server);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $query = $_GET['query'];
        echo $query;
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $service_port = 1111;
        $address = "localhost";

        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if ($socket === false){
            echo "Failed: ". socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\n";
        }

        echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...'\n";
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);

        if ($result === false){
            echo "Failed: ". socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket))."\n";
        }

        $in = $query;
        $out = '';

        echo "Sending...\n";  
        socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
        echo "OK.\n";

        echo "Reading response:\n\n";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 10) > 0) {
            echo $out;
        }

        socket_close($socket);
    }
?>
```